# Multilingual App Toolkit populate xlf file

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, multilingual

We are using multi language resource files in ASP.NET MVC as content files, as we dont need to recompile project to update strings.

we edit the resources using "Multilingual App Toolkit", and to populate the xlf file or to update the resx file after edit the xlf we need to rebuild the project (as described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj569303.aspx))

Is there any way to populate the xlf and to update the resx file after editing, without rebuild project?

Any suggestion will be appreciate.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try "Run custom tool" in the context menu of the xlf and main resx files. You have to run it for each file separately.